# Which is the best way to match short string? regular expression or if else statement?

Tags: regex, if-statement, string-matching

In testOne() I use regex expression use judge if a string contains some specific strings

In testTwo() I use if else statement to to the same thing

I wonder why testTwo() is always faster than testOne() in my test cases

Is regex expression not suitable for the problem? or my regex expression is not well written?

My test code is as follow, thanks very much!

```
public class TestReg {

    static final Pattern PATT = Pattern
            .compile("(tudou|video.sina|v.youku|v.ku6|tv.sohu|v.163|tv.letv|v.ifeng|v.qq|iqiyi|(5)?6)\\.(com|cn)");

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            for (String vurl : TESTCASES) {
                if (PATT.matcher(vurl).find())
                    count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("testOne:" + count);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwo() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            for (String vurl : TESTCASES) {
                if (vurl.indexOf("tudou.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("video.sina.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("v.youku.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("v.ku6.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("56.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("tv.sohu.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("v.163.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("tv.letv.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("v.ifeng.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("v.qq.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("iqiyi.com") != -1
                        || vurl.indexOf("6.cn") != -1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("testOne:" + count);
    }

    static final String[] TESTCASES = {
            "http://blog.csdn.net/v_july_v/article/details/7624837",
            "http://jobs.douban.com/intern/apply/?type=dev&position=intern_sf",
            "https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/index",
            "http://blog.csdn.net/v_july_v/article/details/7624837",
            "http://jobs.douban.com/intern/apply/?type=dev&position=intern_sf",
            "https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/index",
            "http://blog.csdn.net/v_july_v/article/details/7624837",
            "http://jobs.douban.com/intern/apply/?type=dev&position=intern_sf",
            "https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/index",
            "http://blog.csdn.net/v_july_v/article/details/7624837",
            "http://jobs.douban.com/intern/apply/?type=dev&position=intern_sf",
            "https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/index",
            "http://www.56.com/u38/v_NjYyNTUyMjc.html",
            "http://video.sina.com.cn/v/b/69614895-2128825751.html",
            "http://www.tudou.com/programs/view/xcPewAoJ26M",
            "http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMzQ0OTI0MTgw.html",
            "http://www.56.com/u87/v_NjMzMjEzNTY.html",
            "http://tv.sohu/u87/v_NjMzMjEzNTY.html",
            "http://tv.letv/u38/v_NjYyNTUyMjc.html",
            "http://v.ifeng/v/b/69614895-2128825751.html",
            "http://v.qq/programs/view/xcPewAoJ26M",
            "http://v.163/v_show/id_XMzQ0OTI0MTgw.html",
            "http://iqiyi/u87/v_NjMzMjEzNTY.html",
            "http://v.6.cn/u87/v_NjMzMjEzNTY.html" };

}
```

Comment: Are you *actually* only trying to match host names? If so, that's what you should use - otherwise you would match a URL which contained `todou.com` in the path, for example.

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use either:

- Regular expressions are designed to match *patterns*; they're overkill for exact matches
- The `||` statement is a bit painful.

I'd just use a `HashSet<String>`. For each URL, you first use something like the `URL` class to extract the host name, and then see if it's in the set of hosts you're interested in.

Aside from anything else, that will prevent false positives - your current approach would match

```
http://www.someotherhost.com/something/tudou.com
```

... which you don't actually want to.

Comment: I got full url and only want to know if the url's host is in the specific set(tudou.com, video.sina.com, etc), so it's not possible to use HashMap or HashSet. I want to know how to speed up the process~

Comment: @wfweiL Of course it's possible to use a map or a set - you just need to extract the host first.

Comment: I was thinking that extracting host is a more painful job, but I got a limited set of hosts, it may be a good solution in this case! Thank you again:)